# How to handle arrays with QueryRecord?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, nifi-processor

I'm working in Apache NiFi and I've a question: how to handle nested arrays in JSON with `QueryRecord` processor? For example I've a JSON:

```json
{
   "offerName":"Viatti Strada Asimmetrico V-130 205/55 R16 91V",
   "detailedStats":[
      {
         "type":"mobile",
         "clicks":4,
         "spending":"2.95"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I extract array to get the following result:

```json
{
  "offerName": "Viatti Strada Asimmetrico V-130 205/55 R16 91V",
  "type": "mobile",
  "clicks": 4,
  "spending": "2.95"
}
```

[I read about RPATH](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html), but didnt find good examples.

Tried with:

```
SELECT RPATH(detailedStats, '/detailedStats[1]')
  FROM flowfile
```

But it throws error. How can i get expected result with `RPATH`?

Comment: What error do you have? accessor to first element is [0]

Comment: Tried with [0] also.Error is: `java.io.IOException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Could not determine the Avro Schema to use for writing the content: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from QueryRecord[id=276c15fd-19d1-105c-d405-d5bf51052a95]: java.io.IOException: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Could not determine the Avro Schema to use for writing the content`

Answer (score 2):

You can select like below via `QueryRecord` . However it seems you are having an issue while writing. I used `JsonRecordSetWriter` with `Inherent Record Schema`. [this](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) is a good tutorial If you prefer `avro` schema

```sql
SELECT offerName,
       RPATH_STRING(detailedStats, '/type') type,
       RPATH_INT(detailedStats, '/clicks') clicks,
       RPATH_STRING(detailedStats, '/spending') spending
  FROM FLOWFILE
```

result is an array, so you should split it with `$.*` at the downstream

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method might be adding a `JoltTransformJSON` processor with (**shift** type) specification, which's reached from the **Advanced** button of **Settings** tab, with the following code

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "detailedStats": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,offerName)": "offerName",
          "*": "&"          
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

in order to extract your desired result.

Comment: Thanks, but I already did it with JOLT. Just wanted to try and use `QueryRecord`.